# Any way to include a js file in every blade template except for one?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a master template. All the other blade files extend the master. I have js file that I want to include in every blade file except for the homepage (welcome.blade.php). I can include the js file in master but homepage will inherit that too which I don't want. Another thing that I can do is to add the js file manually into all the other blade files which is tired some since I have to do it for every file.
Another thing that can be done is to get the URL via javascript, if it's the URL of the homepage it doesn't add the js file, otherwise, it adds the js file.

Is there any easy way to include that js file in every blade file except for the welcome.blade.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can include the js file in master but homepage will inherit that too which I don't want

Not unless you tell it not to. Proof of concept:

*master.blade.php*

```
<head>
    ...
    @section(head.js)
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/file1.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/file2.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/file3.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/no-home.js') }}"></script>
    @show
</head>
```

*welcome.blade.php* (Don't inherit no-home.js)

```
@section(head.js)
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/file1.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/file2.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/file3.js') }}"></script>
@stop
```

*another-template.blade.php* (inherit everything and add another)

```
@section(head.js)
    @parent
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/file4.js') }}"></script>
@stop
```

Comment: Thank you. i forgot about the @parent.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to not go the js way, you could do this in the mater template:

`<script src="@yield('script_file', 'path/to/script.js')"></script>`

and in your `welcome.blade.php` or any file you want to exclude the script file do:

`@section('script_file', '')`

This will essentially set the `src` for the script to empty; no script